# Doubles, commas and dots

Tags: java, android, decimal

I'm making an Android Java program which is taking double values from the user. If I run the program on the computer, it works great because of the locale of my computer, EN_UK. But when I run it on my mobile phone with FI_FI locale, it won't work. I know the reason: In UK, people use dot as decimal separator but here in Finland, the decimal separator is comma.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
Double returnValue = Double.valueOf(df.format(doubleNumber));
```

When I'm using comma, it says `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1234,5"`.

How can I make it work with them both, comma and dot?

Comment: Why don't you just parse the string and replace the comma with dots if necessary?

Comment: A not so smart solution is to first replace all the commas with dots and then treat the number as if it is formatted with dot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use one of the other constructors of DecimalFormat:

```
new DecimalFormat("#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))
```

And then try and parse it using both separators.

Comment: By far the best answer - if You need DOT instead of COMMA, don't look further.

Answer (score 4):

using `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()`  will produce the default locale's correct symbols, so you will get it right for any platform you run on.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance());
```

Comment: Just for the record, you need this imports in your Java file:
     import java.text.DecimalFormat;
     import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

Answer (score 2):

This should work for both Java(Tested) as well as android :)

- **Class Name: In18Helper.java**

  ```
  package com.akmeher.app.utils;

  import java.text.NumberFormat;
  import java.text.ParseException;
  import java.util.Locale;

  public class In18Helper {
      private final static In18Helper mHelper = new In18Helper();

      public static final In18Helper getInstance() {
          return mHelper;
      }

      public double getDouble(String sValue, Locale locale) {
          NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);

          Number parse = null;
          try {
              parse = numberFormat.parse(sValue);
          } catch (ParseException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return parse == null ? 0 : parse.doubleValue();
      }

  }
  ```
- **Class Name: Application.java**

  ```
  package com.akmeher.app;

  import java.util.Locale;
  import com.akmeher.app.utils.In18Helper;

  public class Application {

      static DataModel[] testData = new DataModel[] {
              new DataModel("1.034567", Locale.ENGLISH),
              new DataModel("1,0345.67", Locale.ENGLISH),
              new DataModel("1.0345,67", Locale.GERMANY),
              new DataModel("1,034,567", Locale.CANADA),
              new DataModel("1.034567", Locale.KOREA),
              new DataModel("1,03.4567", Locale.ITALY) };

      /**
       * @param args
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {

          for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
                      double d = In18Helper.getInstance().getDouble(testData[i].mValue,
                      testData[i].mLocale);

              System.out.println("Trial Value: "+testData[i].mValue+" for Locale: "+testData[i].mLocale+" converted to: "+d);
          }
      }

      private static class DataModel {
          String mValue;
          Locale mLocale;

          public DataModel(String value, Locale locale) {
              this.mLocale = locale;
              this.mValue = value;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Output:**

`Trial Value: 1.034567 for Locale: en converted to: 1.034567
Trial Value: 1,0345.67 for Locale: en converted to: 10345.67
Trial Value: 1.0345,67 for Locale: de_DE converted to: 10345.67
Trial Value: 1,034,567 for Locale: en_CA converted to: 1034567.0
Trial Value: 1.034567 for Locale: ko_KR converted to: 1.034567
Trial Value: 1,03.4567 for Locale: it_IT converted to: 1.03`

Hope this will help somebody to make use of.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Double parseDoubleTL(String value){
    DecimalFormat df =  new DecimalFormat("#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("tr_TR")));
    Double doublePrice = 0.0;
    try {
        doublePrice =  df.parse(value).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.w(MainActivity.TAG,"Couldnt parse TL. Error is "+e.toString());
    }
    return doublePrice;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a best way but worked for me;

```
    Double val=null;
    try{
        val=Double.valueOf(value);
    }catch(Exception e){
        val=Double.valueOf(value.replace(',','.'));
    }
            Double val=null;
    try{
        val=Double.valueOf(value);
    }catch(Exception e){
        val=Double.valueOf(value.replace(',','.'));
    }
    return val;
```

Answer (score -1):

Me Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "1,683.88"
```

... and this work for me

```
replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DecimanFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```