# Change dot to comma at DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

When I use this formatter:

```
java.text.DecimalFormat("#.000");
```

for 1234567/1000000.0

output is:

```
1.235
```

I want it as like that:

```
1,235
```

and tried that:

```
java.text.DecimalFormat("#,000");
```

but it does not work as excepted. How to change dot to comma for my situation?

Comment: Take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584948/doubles-commas-and-dots

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the format symbols using an instance of [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html):

```
public void testDec() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    sym.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
    System.out.println(df.format(1234567/1000000.0));
}
```

Output is

```
1,235
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason your wanting to display a decimal number with a ","?

Otherwise

```
Double answer = 1234567/1000000.0;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
System.out.println(formatter.format(answer*1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code helps

```
public void decimalExample() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    sym.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
    System.out.println(df.format(138947293/1000000.0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace `.` with `,`

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.000");
double d=1234567/1000000.0;
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d).replace(".",","));
```

Out put:

```
1,235
```