# How can I delay the execution of a command?

Tags: java

I have to say I am a newbie in java programming so I would like some help with the following question:

How can I delay a java program so that it waits for a user to give an input?
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1st value= ");
        Scanner aa1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("2nd value= ");
        Scanner bb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

What I get now from this code is "1st value= " and "2nd value= " displayed. After that the program requests the input.
Any ideas on how can I make this simple programm to wait for the user's answer before printing "2nd value= " in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create two `Scanner` variables. You can use one of them and use the function `input.nextInt();` to get both values, where `input` it's the name of the `Scanner` variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1, number2;

        System.out.println("1st value= ");
        number1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("2nd value= ");
        number2 = input.nextInt();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but why is Scanner method not suitable???

Comment: @BramFran When you use `Scanner bb1 = new Scanner(System.in);` you are creating a new `Scanner` variable named `bb1` but you are not reading the input.

Comment: what if I want the input to be double instead of int? because I make it number1 = input.nextDouble(); (NO ERRORS) and then when i type the number 1.5 for example I get this crash report:                                                                                                               Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at test2.main(test.java:10)

Comment: @BramFran Try using a coma. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584948/doubles-commas-and-dots.

Answer (score 3):

Ask for input from the user:

```
int index = aa1.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use only one `Scanner` variable. This is the solution :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("1st value= " + str);

        str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("2nd value= " + str);
    }
}
```

You can see the different `next***()` on the doc on this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.

I advise you to follow a Java formation if you want to code in this language.

Comment: Where is the name of the class and the main method?

Comment: @Error404 Thank you for your suggestions for improvement

Comment: Glad for be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You must first import the Scanner before your Main class.

   `import java.util.Scanner;`
2. You must then create a Scanner variable. I use "in" in my example:

   `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

   3. This will force the program to wait for user input.

` import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Example{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String name;
        String address;
        String cityStateZip;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //User input
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your address:");
        address = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your City, State, and Zip code:");
        cityStateZip = in.nextLine();`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1st value= " 
            + input.nextInt()
            + "2nd value= "
            + input.nextInt());
}
```

For further reference to can go through Scanner java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

Add necessary imports by pressing control+shift+o after you have typed the main function.

```
 public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
    // Take Scanner object
     Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    // Ask user for 1st input
    System.out.println("Enter 1st value:");
    String value=scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("1st value is ="+s);
    // Ask user for 2nd input
    System.out.println("Enter 2nd value:");
    value=scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("2nd value is ="+s);



    }
```

NOTE : `scanner.nextLine()` will read the user input as a `String`,
If you need the input as `int` , use `scanner.nextInt();` For float use `scanner.nextFloat()` and so on.

Now the console is halted for user input and then asks for second input.

Hope it helps.