# Java DecimalFormat output with dot separator

Tags: java, decimalformat

I use Decimalformat two get two decimals with this line of code

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

My outputs is for example like this

```
568,99  
1090,33
12897,45
233567,77
```

How can I set the decimalformat to output like this?

```
568,99  
1.090,33
12.897,45
233.567,77
```

Is there a way with the methods from Decimalformat to do this.
With codes like these

```
 df.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
 df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
 df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
```

I never extended my knowledge about DecimalFormat, that's why I'm asking.

1. Is this possible to do with the decimalformat code? How?
2. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use the appropriate Locale.

Comment: i.e., `NumberFormat.getInstance(myLocale);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584948/doubles-commas-and-dots

Comment: `"Is this possible to do with the decimalformat code?"` -- Please read the DecimalFormat API, and it will explicitly tell you, **no**, that you should use a NumberFormat. I'm sorry if this  sounds like a RTFM comment, but in this case, it directly addresses your question.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I found what I was looking for through the links.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it does not look nice with the dots.
Look here for example.

```
1.234.345,00
```

So I changed to empty space instead with this line...

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
```

that created this

```
1 234 345,00
```